# 16.04 Freezing after login(except guest session)

Tags: 16.04, freeze

I just upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04.

Every time I log in as my user the computer freezes within 10 seconds. But if I log in to a guest session everything works fine.

Anyone have anything I can try to get this fixed?

I thought I was dealing with a gpu driver issue since I'm using a radeon gpu and I've heard people have had issues with them on 16.04. But then I discovered that guest sessions run fine using the same driver. So now I'm not sure what to look for.

---

**What I've tried:**

- dpkg repair during boot
- Logging in through a TTY and running `sudo chown -R $USER: ~`

**Aditional details:**

- The desktop loads and startup processes start before the screen freezes
- When the screen freezes I can move the mouse at first, then the screen blacks out for a second and when it returns the mouse is frozen also
- If I log in to a guest session after logging in to my user through a TTY the screen freezes

Comment: Then it's probably something in your home directory. I would start with making sure that you (and not root) are the owner of all files and directories in $HOME.

Comment: Can you log into your user account through a TTY? Press CTRL+ALT+F1 and enter your username and password. Now would be a great occasion to fix possibly messed up file ownerships using the command `sudo chown -R $USER: ~` as Gunnar just said. You log out again afterwards using the `exit` command and you switch back to the GUI using CTRL+ALT+F7.

Comment: Yes, I can log into my account through a TTY. I ran `sudo chown -R $USER: ~` but it didn't fix the issue. The screen still freezes after logging in to my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A last resort, when something within your home directory has been messed up, but you don't know what the problem is, is to rename it and create a brand new home directory.

Assuming that your username is moss, running these commands from a TTY would do it:

```
cd /home
sudo mv moss moss.old
sudo mkdir moss
sudo cp -rT /etc/skel/ moss
sudo chown -R moss:moss moss
```

That would allow you to log in to your user account from the login screen.

Then you could copy/move cherry picked contents from `/home/moss.old`.

Comment: When I try to rename the directory with `mv` I get the error `mv: cannot move 'moss' to 'moss.old': Device or resource busy`.

Comment: @moss: I see. Have done this a few times myself, and never encountered that objection. Probably you need to shut down one or more applications/processes.

Comment: I've been trying to get this working since yesterday. I can't find any processes running in /home/moss. I also tried logging in as a different user, but I still get the error.

Comment: Ok, I managed to complete the commands. But now how do I access the data from `moss.old`?

Comment: @moss: You use the terminal or Files or whatever... For instance: `cp -rT ../moss.old/Documents Documents`

Comment: Except all files from my old home folder are encrypted.

Comment: @moss: Well, that doesn't make it easier... Possibly it makes this approach impossible, and you'll need to revert to the old home.

Comment: Alright, how do I revert to the old home?

Comment: Nevermind I was able to recover the data with `ecryptfs-recover-private`